# Security of SQL Server 2008 with Integrated Security

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

when using SQL Server 2008 with Integrated Security on a windows Domain along with a C# client application, is the data transferred between the client and the SQL server encrypted? 
If so what encryption mechanism is employed?

Comment: You can turn on SSL.  On the other hand, if they have access to the database directly you have to wonder what it matters.

Comment: No, only the login credentials will be passed to SQL server encrypted.

Comment: thanks i know that but are you saying the data is NOT encrypted when using integrated security?

Comment: @Cory Between WCF clients and servers, i am using ws-security. Do you know if SQL supports this ?

Comment: The data is NOT automatically encrypted. You need to enable that yourself.

Comment: @Cory He doesn't need TDE unless he wants the database to be encrypted at rest.

Comment: @Cory "TDE does not provide encryption across communication channels"

Comment: My bad on TDE; comment retracted. You'll have to come up with a plan, whether it's [SSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx) or something else. ws-security is supported by SQL Server for authentication but I think that's on the list of features that are deprecated in future versions of SQL server.

Comment: so is SSL the only option here ?

Comment: @user1438082 Yes, I suppose it is, but you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem, since anyone can easily bypass this "security" by logging onto the database themselves.

Comment: @emodendroket well for that i have username password - surely everyone is in the same boat regarding security - For me the best i got is : Integrated security, TDE and now SSL. What more can i do ?

Comment: You have to insert a layer between the database and the client if you want to secure anything.  Otherwise it isn't secure at all.

Comment: @emodendroket oh i have that too - a Data access layer - this is a WCF service. Anything else needed - do you think?

Comment: If the DAL is running on the client that doesn't help.

Comment: @emodendroket No, It is running on it's own server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - It is not encrypted - Use SSL